# Isotope grid item with position: relative

Tags: css, layout, css-position, jquery-isotope

## context

I want to build a Isotope grid layout with infinite scroll loading.

## needs

I need to give a relative position to `.grid-item` in order to position its child elements with `position: absolute` related to parent element `.grid-item`.

```
<div class="grid">
   <article class=".grid-item" ?>  <!-- position: relative -->
     <img>                         <!-- position: absolute -->
     <h2>                          <!-- position: absolute -->
   </article>
</div>
```

## problem

After infinite scroll load, a callback is fired to sort layout with new grid items: `$('.grid').isotope('reloadItems').isotope();` but this items are positioned in the top of container `.grid` overlaping previous grid items. This behavior is fixed giving a static position to .grid-item, but I really need the relative position, as explained before.

## question

There is some way to get Isotope to work with a `.grid-item` relatively positioned?

I don't know how to build a codepen with all of this, but here is a provisional URL with my project, showing this behavior. After infinite scroll load, new items go to the top of `.grid` container:

https://stage.e451.net/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another "my fault" answer :(

The callback to Isotope, after infinite scroll loading, lacks a `viewportWidth` variable declaration:

```
if (viewportWidth>=768) {
 $('.grid').isotope('reloadItems').isotope();
};
```

So, Isotope didn't manage new grid items after load. This work:

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
if (viewportWidth>=768) {
 $('.grid').isotope('reloadItems').isotope();
};
```